# Putting an ajax call results into a variable that can be manipulated as a div

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm making an ajax call and get results back.

```
  $.get('/page.html',function(data){

      var myData = data;

    });
```

Is there a way that i can store the results in a variable and then manipulate that variable as if it was a container? If i make a change, something like this:

```
$('#myData ul').remove()
```

Now the myData variable still has the information but now with the ul removed?

Comment: Let me make sure I understand. You're getting the returned data, and you're wanting to load that information into a div>ul? If so, you can treat it as you would any other array and just loop/append the data to your div.

Comment: I'm trying to put the information into a temporary div (myData) that i can manipulate

Answer (score 1):

Provided the data returned by ajax call is html, you can create the object using jQuery($) and treat it as DOM element to make modifications.

```
data = "<div> <h1> Sample header </h1> <ul> <li> List item 1 </li> <li> List item 2 </li> </ul>";
var myData = $(data);
myData.find('ul').remove();
$('body').append(myData);
```

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ex0yuL7s/1/

Comment: Sorry... doesn't seem to work for me. I did this:  var myData = $(data);myData.find('ul').remove();$('#results').html(myData); .... When it displays, the ul isn't gone. Still there.

Comment: `myData.contents().filter( "ul" ).remove();`

Comment: That should remove them as well. However, you could always just skip that and do `var myData = $(data); $('#results').html(myData).filter('ui').remove()`